# Does google chrome has a download option 'Open with' (like firefox and IE)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I have used IE and Firefox which has the download option open with which can be used when you don't want to save the file to HDD but simply want to view it. Does google chrome have this option? Chrome always download the file into the donloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

Technically all that IE and firefox are doing in this situation is downloading to a temporary folder. Often that temporary folder is not cleared automatically either, so you just end up with two folders unless you clear manually.

Comment: But temp folder will be cleared when I run ccleaner or restart the computer. Download folder doesn't

Comment: Restarting often doesn't clear this folder, cleaner does though. It's not hard to delete items from the downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

In short,Google chrome doesn't have feature to open with while downloading the files.You have option to chose the download location or specify the download location in the settings page